# React Router - Preserve current route after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to SPA development. I use React and React Router and made simple app. It has two pages: public and protected. User can see protected page only when he was signed in. I use firebase for managing users.

The problem is when I go to protected page, log in and can see its content, I then resresh the page and redirected to "default" state which is public page.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
const ProtectedPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Protected page. </h1>
      <Link to="/">Public resources</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

const PublicPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Public page. </h1>
      <p> Login to see protected resources </p>
      <Link to="/protected">Protected resources</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      uuid: ''
    }
  }

  login() {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
      console.log('Sign in ', user.displayName);
      this.setState({
        username: user.displayName,
        uuid: user.uuid
      });
    });
  }

  logout() {
    auth.signOut().then(() => {
      console.log('Sign out ');
      this.setState({
        username: '',
        uuid: '' 
      });
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.releaseFirebaseAuthHandler = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        this.setState({
          username: user.displayName,
          uuid: user.uuid
        });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.releaseFirebaseAuthHandler();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="navbar">
          <nav className="navbar-nav">
            { this.state.username ? 
              <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button> :
              <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button> }
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
              <Route exact path="/" component={PublicPage} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={ProtectedPage} isAuthenticated={this.state.uuid !== ''} />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is it possible to preserve localhost:3000/protected page after refreshing it without involving the server?

Comment: The real question here is how to keep the user authenticated after refresh, no ? You can store the uuid in the localStorage. Then in app constructor : `this.state = { uuid: localStorage.getItem('uuid') || ''}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is not preserved across multiple sessions, for this purpose you can use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 2):

In your code you redirect to `pathname: '/'` if user is not authenticated:

```
const PrivateRoute = (...) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
   isAuthenticated 
     ? <Component {...props}/>
     : <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: props.location }
       }}/>
   )}/>
 )
```

If you would like to keep `/protected` in url one way to do it is to replace redirect with something like `<div>Please login</div>`